# perl - slow parsing and send to database

Tags: sql, perl

I have this code in perl, and I want send in a database.

my code :

```
my $dir = '/mnt/Logs/';
foreach my $fp (glob("$dir/SESSIONS*")) {
  printf "%s\n", $fp;
  open my $fh, "<", $fp or die "can't read open '$fp': $OS_ERROR"
while ($fh) {

    @line = split(' ',$_);      
    print "$line[0] $line[1] $line[2] $line[3] $line[4] $line[5]\n";
}
```

logs :

```
           SID OSUSER                    TERMINAL        PROGRAM                    
    ---------- ------------------------- --------------- -------------------------  
             1 titi                    toto     tata          
             2 gigi                    gogo     gaga          
             4 fifi                    fofo     fafa 
3 rows selected.
```

my question is how to do this :

```
SID OSUSER                  TERMINAL PROGRAM  rows selected         
  1 titi                    toto     tata     3    
  2 gigi                    gogo     gaga     3   
  4 fifi                    fofo     fafa     3
```

Comment: I don't see any database related code. How do you send the data to the database?

Comment: for this moment i want only print

Comment: Also, what is `$fh`? Or did you mean `while (<$fh>)`?

Comment: yes, i mean while (<$fh>)

Comment: @choroba yes, i mean while (<$fh>)

Comment: Also, why does it say 4 rows when there are only 3?

Comment: @ yes you are right

Comment: how can i script that with fast printing

Comment: @dfgert: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. What, exactly, do you want to change about the current behaviour?

Comment: my question is how to do : SID OSUSER                  TERMINAL PROGRAM  rows selected         
  1 titi                    toto     tata     3    
  2 gigi                    gogo     gaga     3   
  4 fifi                    fofo     fafa     3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know the number of rows until you've processed them all. So, keep the output in a buffer, and print it at the end of the file processing:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature qw{ say };

    open my $fh, '<', 'log' or die $!;

    my @buffer;
    while (<$fh>) {
        next if $. < 3;
        if (/^([0-9]+) rows selected\.$/) {
            die "Wrong number of rows reported: $1, seen ", scalar @buffer
                if $1 != @buffer;
        } else {
            push @buffer, [ split ' ' ];
        }
    }
    for (@buffer) {
        say join "\t", @$_, scalar @buffer;
    }
```

or process the file twice. In the first run, just count the lines, in the second one, print them one by one, appending the count:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'log' or die $!;

1 while <$fh>;
my $size = $. - 3;
seek $fh, $. = 0, 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    next if $. < 3;
    if (/^([0-9]+) rows selected\.$/) {
        die "Wrong number of rows reported: $1, seen ", $size
            if $1 != $size;
    } else {
        say join "\t", split(' '), $size;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not what i want

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @choroba: It seems unlikely :-)